# Regex to match array of strings and optional array of strings

Tags: arrays, regex, option-type

I am making a syntax highlighting service for guitar chord sheets. I am trying to highlight the guitar chords and not the lyrics. However, it gets complicated when guitar chords can be comprised of chords + extensions.

For example,

```
God Is So Good
(capo 1 for Eb)

[Verse 1]
D          Em     A7         D
God is so good,  God is so good;
D         G     Em       D   A7 D
God is so good, He’s so good to me.
```

I need regex to capture not only "D", "E" but also the "Dm", "Em7", "Dmaj7", "D/F#" and etc.

I have two arrays here, and the first array is capturing the chords and the second array is the optional extensions.

> Array1 = {"A", "Bb", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "Eb", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"}
>
> Array2 = {"", "/", "m", "-", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "sus", "maj"}

How do I go about writing the regex to `contain` strings in **Array 1**, followed by `optional` strings in **Array 2**?

My initial take on this was to create a long regex that captures all possible chord expressions, but I want to know if there is a better way.

Edit: new example:
revo, that regex didn't work with this example: something like D/F# should be matched as well.

```
 G                     D/F#      
 How great is our God, sing with me,
 Em7                   D/F#      
 How great is our God, all will see,
```

edit: `\b(?:[BE]b?|[ACDFG]#?)(?:sus|maj|[-1-9/m])*(?!.[a-z]|[A-Z])` works for me at the moment.

[Chord Editor working in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abGas.png)

Comment: It is like writing a similar regex to this `\b(?:[BE]b?|[ACDFG]#?)(?:sus|maj|[-1-9\/m])*(?!\S)`. See live demo here https://regexr.com/42b43

Comment: Do you want to match `Eb` in `(capo 1 for Eb)` as well?

Comment: If `Eb` in `Eb)` should match doesn't it mean `)` is working like an optional character in `Array2`?

Comment: revo, thank you! but that regex could not capture D/F#. How can one write contains array 1 string, followed by optional array 2 strings?

Comment: According to your current rules `D/F#` should not be returned as one match. Because you say it should match a mandatory value from Array1 (where here it is `D`) then any optional value from Array2 (which it is `/`). So it should match `D/` in `D/F#` then - if you require - `F#` as another match. Please elaborate on these conflicts.

Comment: @revo I was able to change your regex and replaced `(?!\S)` to `(?![a-z])` and worked.
`\b(?:[BE]b?|[ACDFG]#?)(?:sus|maj|[-1-9\/m])*(?![a-z])`

Comment: @revo you are right. I did not provide the correct rules. I will adjust in my question. Thank you.

Comment: Okay then you need this `\b(?:(?:[BE]b?|[ACDFG]#?)(?:sus|maj|[-1-9\/m])*)+(?![a-zA-Z])`. See live demo here https://regexr.com/42b8j

Comment: Edit: I tweaked the regex a little bit to avoid capturing A in lyrics like "A beautiful flower" - `\b(?:[BE]b?|[ACDFG]#?)(?:sus|maj|[-1-9\/m])*(?!.[a-z])`

Comment: Oops. Your last comment will destroy the whole thing. It wouldn't be possible to have a bulletproof regular expression solution to this problem.

Comment: @revo Thank you. Could you write it as an answer so I can select it as an answer? (note: I added . before [a-zA-Z] so that it can avoid highting "A beautiful flower" in the lyrics line.

Comment: But it will avoid matching `D` in `D G/F#` if you enable case-insensitivity.

Comment: You are correct that there is no bulletproof regular expression solution for this problem. I plan to use some additional coding to pick out the chord line from the lyrics line and apply the regex. However, adding a little . captures 99% of them time, because in chord sheets, people don't usually capitialize A in the middle of the stanza.

Comment: This `\b(?:[BE]b?|[ACDFG]#?)(?:sus|maj|[-1-9\/m])*(?!.[a-z])` works. But `\b(?:(?:[BE]b?|[ACDFG]#?)(?:sus|maj|[-1-9\/m])*)+(?![a-zA-Z])` doesn't work when there is 1 white space between the chords `  D G/F# `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex doesn't have to be very long. You don't need to write out *every* possibility like this:

```
 A|A#|B|Bb|C|C#...
```

you can shorten the first part to this:

```
[BE]b?|[ACDFG]#?
```

Shortening the second part:

```
sus|maj|[-1-9\/m]
```

And you just combine the two:

```
\b(?:[BE]b?|[ACDFG]#?)(?:sus|maj|[-1-9\/m])?(?:sus|maj|[-1-9\/m])
```

Note that the `\b` at the start and `(?:sus|maj|[-1-9\/m])` at the end. This ensures that substrings that are part of a word are not matched. Hence, things like `G` in "God" will not be matched.

Obviously, if your array contents are unknown at compile time, you can't use such "tricks" and have to write out every possibility.

Comment: You should not use `\b` at the end because you don't know `/` or `-` may occur at the end or not. See my comment above.

Comment: @revo Oh I see the problem. But your solution doesn't match the `Eb` in the brackets... Thinking of something new now...

Comment: @revo What about `(?!\w)`?

Comment: Well then that should be cleared by OP as for now it's like an optional character from second array.

Comment: I should prevent to guess until OP makes things clear.

Comment: I suggest you rollback your edit to `(?!\w)` while being awaited a reply.

Comment: / or - will not occur at the end.